# How to get UUID for apple binaries on Linux

Tags: ios, linux, amazon-ec2, uuid, mach-o

I am trying to figure out how to get the UUID for a apple executable file while on Linux (EC2).

When on Mac, I can use the following line to get the UUID:

```
xcrun dwarfdump --uuid
```

I learned that there is a version of dwarfdump on Linux, so I used the following command to install it:

```
sudo yum install libdwarf-tools
```

However when I run the utility and look at the help screen there is no "-u" or "-uuid" command, and trying to run them does't do anything (there is no error message). The commands available look like it is a different tool that what I am looking for. I tried some of the arguments like "-a" and "-b" against the same file which worked on Mac, but I never get any output.

Does anyone know where I can get the version of dwarfdump that supports UUID for Linux? Or any other easy way to get the UUID from a file? I know it's in the binary file somewhere but I don't want to have to write an entire command parser just for this.

Comment: What utility are you running (from libdwarf-tools)?

Comment: The utility from libdwarf-tools is just called 'dwarfdump'. Actually I am just running this command from the current directory so I don't know 100% it is coming from libdwarf-tools, however dwarfdump didn't work before I installed libdwarf-tools so it must be from there. What utility should I be using so I can get the UUID?

Answer (score 0):

I talked to the developer of this tool and the problem is that MachO is not currently supported.

So it looks like the only way to do this would be to write a tool from scratch to do it, or to modify an existing tool. I think ATOSL might be able to be used for this purpose.